# SonarQube language plugin development

Tags: java, sonarqube

I started development of my own plugin and have a trouble about FileSystem:

My Sensor implementation like a sonar-reference-plugin:

```
public class PLPlusCodeSensor implements Sensor {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private final FileSystem filesystem;
    private final Settings settings;

    public PLPlusCodeSensor(Settings settings, FileSystem filesystem) {
        this.filesystem = filesystem;
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldExecuteOnProject(Project project) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void analyse(Project project, SensorContext sensorContext) {
        for(InputFile file : filesystem.inputFiles(filesystem.predicates().all())) {
            log.info("Processing file " + file.absolutePath());
            Measure measure = new Measure(PLPlusMetrics.LineLength, 85d);
            sensorContext.saveMeasure(file, measure);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getName();
    }
}
```

but there is no output about any file in source dir:

```
18:04:27.707 INFO  - Sensor com.sbt.tools.sonarqube.plplus.PLPlusCodeSensor
18:04:27.707 INFO  - Sensor com.sbt.tools.sonarqube.plplus.PLPlusCodeSensor (done) | time=0ms
```

here is my sonar-project.properties flie:

```
sonar.projectKey=plplus-test
sonar.projectName=PLPlus Test Analysis
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=c:/dev/plplus/src
```

here is content of src dir:

```
C:\dev\plplus\src>dir
 Том в устройстве C имеет метку Windows7_OS
 Серийный номер тома: 18DB-13C8

 Содержимое папки C:\dev\plplus\src

23.12.2015  17:59    <DIR>          .
23.12.2015  17:59    <DIR>          ..
23.12.2015  15:54                 0 test.plp
           1 файлов              0 байт
           2 папок  98 023 743 488 байт свободно

C:\dev\plplus\src>
```

Please, help me to understand, why filesystem.inputFiles(filesystem.predicates().all()) returns an empty iterator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get a file from fileSystem api it has to be indexed. In order to do so, you have to either define a language that will declare the extension you are looking for or import all source files using `sonar.import_unknown_files=true` (with SQ 5.1+)

Comment: Thank You! To avoid situation above I've created and registered Language extension and added a sonar.language to sonar-project.properties.